# Will search engines index an html fragment if it doesn't have an html and body root element?

Tags: angularjs, search

I've developed a single page app and it's working well, but I want to split the content into multiple urls. The main page loads html fragments using angular, I was wondering if I serve the same fragments up to a search engine if the missing <html> and <body> elements will impact search ranking in a negative way. I have searched on both google and stack overflow, but if someone has asked this before it's been drowned out by other similar questions.

Comment: Wouldn't do any good serving partials...page would have no title for starters and invalid html would be a red flag. Lots of solutions around how to serve SEO pages for SPA's

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I wanted to know. Unfortunately, every solution I've found so far involved changing something server-side, and that isn't an option for me due to the fact that this is 100% static hosting.

Comment: Move hosts...hosting is cheap

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out a working solution. Using the [$locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) service, map the urls (like /about.html and /faq.html) to the html fragments (/about-fragment.html and /faq-fragment.html) with the templateUrl argument:

```js
module.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

        // about page
        .when("/about.html", {
            "templateUrl" : "about-fragment.html"
        })
        // faq page
        .when("faq.html", {
            "templateUrl" : "faq-fragment.html"
        });
}]);
```

Put just the content fragment into the <file>-fragment.html, then copy the content into the full html wrapper at <file>.html. This way, users will see the same content as a crawler would, while still interacting with the site as a single-page app. A nice last step would be to embed a javascript redirect in each full-content page to navigate back to the url for the single page app, then use angular to switch the url back to the original - this way a user who bookmarked /about.html or /faq.html and then navigated directly to that page would still get the same single-page app experience.

Comment: This is kind of a hack but I think it will work. Plan on trying it when I have time.